# Django 1.5 integrity error : (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")

Tags: python, django

I'm having some trouble with the edit user function of my application.

this is the code in views.py:

```
def edit_user_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserProfileEditForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('com:lebay_view_user_profile', args=(user.pk,)))
else:
    form = UserProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.user)

return render_to_response('lebay/edit_user_profile.html', {
    'form': form,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And this is from form.py:

```
class UserProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    zipcode = USZipCodeField()
    phone = USPhoneNumberField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address_line_1', 'address_line_2', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'phone']
```

I think django tries to create a new user instead of updating it, so there's an error caused by two user with the same username... but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `instance` into the form when you instantiate it, both initially and as a result of a post action. Here is a simpler version of the common Django form instantiation pattern:

```
def edit_user_profile(request):
    form = UserProfileEditForm(data=request.POST or None,
                               instance=request.user.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('com:lebay_view_user_profile', args=(user.pk,)))

    return render_to_response('lebay/edit_user_profile.html', {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your user you have to use the `instance` argument when you create your form. See the example extracted from the documentation ([Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method))

```
f = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, instance=a)
f.save()
```